# Spring JDBC & Oracle DB 12c: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type. Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, oracle12c

I'm struggling with following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [update EVALUATION_SHEET set STATUS=?, LAST_EDITED=? where id=?]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

Which is thrown here:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("update E_SHEET set STATUS=?, LAST_EDITED=? where id=?",
                new Object[]{eSheet.getStatus().ordinal(), eSheet.getLastEditDate(), eSheet.getId()},
                new Object[]{OracleTypes.NUMBER, OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP, OracleTypes.NUMBER});
```

The database table is created as follows:

```
create table E_SHEET (
  ID number not null unique,
  ID_POSITION number not null,
  STATUS number default 0 not null,
  ID_EXAMINER number not null,
  LAST_EDITED timestamp not null);
```

I have no idea what is causing the problem. This method:

```
 eSheet.getLastEditDate()
```

returns java.util.Date object. I am using Spring JDBC template with Spring Boot and Oracle DB 12c as a datasource.

Comment: last_edited is a timestamp, it means that you will need to use the timestamp object: `new Timestamp(eSheet.getLastEditDate().getTime())`

Comment: That exception statement basically just says "I got this other exception". Post *that* one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after the spring documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html, an update would work like this:

`jdbcTemplate.update("update t_actor set last_name = ? where id = ?", "Banjo", 5276L);`

or like this

`jdbcTemplate.update("update orders set shipping_charge = shipping_charge * ? / 100 where id = ?", pct, orderId);`

But you are passing arrays of Objects as parameters to the method.

Why not just this?

`jdbcTemplate.update("update E_SHEET set STATUS=?, LAST_EDITED=? where id=?",  eSheet.getStatus().ordinal(), eSheet.getLastEditDate(), eSheet.getId());`